# Get Object reference when using context rewrite path

Tags: c#, nullreferenceexception, identify

I get this error when i have this in my codebehind: if(Page.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)

```
  System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
```

This error show when i use context.RewritePath method
http://localhost/page.apsx?id=22 --> http://localhost/hello-world/

Page.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated return True when i go to page.aspx?id=22 but i get

```
  System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
```

error when i go to /hello-world/ url.

Comment: Would it be possible to post a little bit of code and maybe the full exception details? It would help diagnosing the issue. Thanks.

Comment: When i try to debbug the code i can view any info and get the error right away. Any my url rewriting is like this:

Answer (score 0):

If the url.Contains("List") then rewrite the url like this:

```
context.RewritePath(Utility.WebRoot + "List/Add.aspx", false);
```

My rewriter is not more complicate then that.